# Windows SSH client

Tags: ssh

I've been using [puttytray](http://www.xs4all.nl/~whaa/putty/) with these [color schemes](http://www.igvita.com/2008/04/14/custom-putty-color-themes/). Any other good options out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PuTTY is the best open-source terminal emulator out there. Unless you're having issues with it, there's probably no reason to change. That said, I have met several network engineers who much prefer [SecureCRT](http://www.vandykesoftware.com/products/securecrt/index.html). It's main feature is session/connection management; when you're making a change that needs you logged in to 15 devices at the same time, having a good tab management system is a big advantage.

Comment: PuTTY is the king. Putty Connection Manager (http://puttycm.free.fr/) and mRemote (http://www.mremote.org/wiki/) are good apps that have the tabbing, etc.  that PuTTY lacks.

Comment: Ooh - I hadn't heard of either of those before. A colleague of mine likes PuTTY Tab (http://www.raisin.de/putty-tabs/putty-tabs.html). The question never really comes up for me; I just open a session to a bastion Linux host running Screen (http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/); session management, tabs, logging, and entirely keyboard driven.

Comment: What I realy hate about putty is how copy-paste is done...

Comment: @softly.lt: That can be changed. Look at 'Window -> Selection' in PuTTY configuration. I have my default for all sessions set to 'Windows (Middle extends, Right brings up menu)'.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [comparison of SSH clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) on Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks! I have some keyboard problems, lets see if those that support Full keyboard mapping help.

Answer (score 2):

I use [SSH Secure Shell Client 3.2.9](http://web.wm.edu/it/index.php?id=2928) because it has support for both ssh client and ftps client.

But.. I tend to come back to PuTTY.

Comment: Do you really mean [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) and not [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a new program just today through superuser.com and that is [ZOC SSH/Telnet Client](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html).

ZOC is like SecureCRT (also for $$) but available for Mac and Windows in very similar versions so I can use it on my Macbook and Windows Desktop with the same configuration and don't have to do thins differently.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, one of the best SSH Windows clients is [XShell 3.x](http://www.netsarang.com/download/down_xsh3.html). A few years I used Putty, and it's nice, but XShell is the best one!

Comment: Xshell is awesome, i switched to it from SecureCRT 3-4 years ago and haven't looked back

Answer (score 1):

I use [SSH Secure Shell](http://www.ssh.com/support/downloads/secureshellwks/non-commercial.html) which is now called "SSH Tectia Client".

Note: It has a "sister" sftp product as well which I found useful.

Comment: Do you use it for any particular reason?

Comment: I had a look around and it was the best free (non-commercial product) that I could find. It has a "sister" sftp product as well which was useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Bitvise Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier)

Answer (score 0):

It costs $$$ but I use SecureCRT + SecureFX. Support has been excellent over the years and "it just works".

Answer (score 0):

I've used Secure Shell Client for some time. It just works for me. I use it to remote access my server when necessary, and it includes a SFTP client as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with PuTTY. it may not have a lot of frills, but at least it works!

Answer (score 0):

Tunnelier tends to leave lots of bash.exe files running behind, if you don't log out properly